# MySQL : how to split text and number with "-"

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to rewrite a number of user id which is splited by "-" between text and number. For example:

- KT-12345
- BA-98765
- CC-98765
- ITA-87987

From a huge amount of data which is mixed up with text and number. For example:

- KT98798
- CC94788
- BB87600

So the question is : I would like to make the user id from the 2nd examples into the first one. How to achieve it in MySQL. Please suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN floor(substr(name, 3,1)) > 0
THEN CONCAT_WS('-', SUBSTRING(name, 1, 2), SUBSTRING(name, 3, LENGTH(name)))
ELSE CONCAT_WS('-', SUBSTRING(name, 1, 3), SUBSTRING(name, 4, LENGTH(name)))
END AS new_name
FROM test
```

Comment: Hi @cetver, your solution is close but I've got some issues. If the user_id prefixed with 2 characters it works well. But if it begins with 3 chars, It results like MK-D-12345. In this case of 3 chars prefixed. I'd like to make it as "MKD-12345". Please suggest

Comment: cetver, your solution is super. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No "SELECT" data but UPDATE:

```
UPDATE `table` SET field = REPLACE(field, '-', '');
```

Answer (score -1):

here an example how to use it in php

```
$str = 'abc123';
preg_match('#([a-z]*)(\d*)#', $str, $match);
echo 'alpha: ' . $match[1];
echo 'num: ' . $match[2];?>
```